# Should I introduce redundancy into model design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I am trying to design a new system for tracking sales. A simplistic version of my data models are:

```
public class Sale 
{
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletedDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual List<SaleItem> SaleItems { get; set; }

    public decimal Total
    {
       get
        {
            return SaleItems.Sum(i => i.Price);
        }
    }
}


public class SaleItem 
{
    public int SaleItemId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Sale Sale { get; set; }

}
```

I am now writing some reports which total the sales value for between a specified period. I have the following code to do that:

```
List<Sale> dailySales = db.Sales
                          .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CompletedDateTime) >= fromParam)
                          .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CompletedDateTime) <= toParam)
                          .ToList();

decimal total = dailySales.Sum(x => x.Total);
```

This is working ok and giving me the expected result. I feel like this might give me problems further down the line though once large datasets get involved. I assume having to load all the Sale's into a list would become resource intensive, plus my actual implementation has tax, costs etc. associated with each SaleItem so again becomes more complex.

The following would allow me to do all the processing on the database, however it is not possible to do this as the DB does not have a representation for Total, so EF throws an error:

```
Decimal total = db.Sales.Sum(x=>x.Total);
```

Which leads me to my question. I could set me model as the following and each time I add a SaleItem, make sure I update the Total:

```
public class Sale 
{
    ...    
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

This would then allow me to query the database as required, and I assume will be less resource intensive. The flip side though is that I have reduced redundancy into the database. Is the latter way, the better method of dealing with this or is there an alternative method I haven't even considered that is better?

Comment: It depends whether you read more often, or write more often

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many factors. For instance, how often will you require the "Total" amount to be available? And how many SaleItems are there usually in a Sale?

If we're talking about, say, a supermarket kind of sale where you have... say... maximum of maximums 200 items. It's quite okay to just quickly calculate it on the fly. Then again, if this ever gets mapped to a RDBMS and if you have all the SaleItems in one single table, having an index on the foreign key (which links each individual SaleItem to its Sale) is a must, otherwise performance will take a huge hit once you start to have millions of transactions to sift through.

Answering the second half of your question, having redundancy is not always a bad thing... you just need to make sure that if each Sale ever needs to get its List modified, at the end of it the Total is recalculated. It's slightly dangerous (redundancy always has this attached burden) but you just need to ensure that whatever has the potential to change the Sale, does so in a way (maybe even with a trigger in the RDBMS) that the total will be automatically recalculated.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is pretty good advice.  I would add that managed redundancy is OK, but don't start from the assumption that you're going to need it.  Find out through load testing whether you have a performance issue, don't assume there will be one without testing for it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that, it's much more efective to calculate totals on the DB side instead of loading the whole list and calculating it on the application.

I think you're missing that you can make a LINQ query that gets the SUM of related children entities.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    var totalSales = ctx.Sales
        .Select(s => s.SaleItems.Sum(si => si.Price)) // Total of each Sale
        .Sum(tsi => tsi); // Sum of the total of each sale
}
```

You can of course shape the query to bring additional information, projecting the result in an anonymous class or in a class created ad-hoc for this purpose.

Of course, this EF query will be translated into a SQL query and executed on the server side.

When you start using LINQ to EF it's not very obvious how to get what you want, but in most occassions you can do it.